# custom single product banner depending on product tag

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to add some picture / banner to single product page, but only for specific products based on product TAG. For example i have product TAG named PROMO, and i would like to add some banner for product with this tag.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_content', 10, 2);
function my_content() {
    $product_tags = array( 'some tag' );

echo '<div class="my_content"><img class="size-full wp-image-42086" src="url of picture" alt="" width="280" height="23"></a></div>';
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping trough the tags to see if "some tag" exists, and then execute the banner code.

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_tag' );
 
    // Loop through each product tag for the current product
    if ( count( $terms ) > 0 ) {
 
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 
           // Product Tag Name
            $term_name = $term->name;
            if ($term_name == "some tag") {
     
     echo '<div class="my_content"><img class="size-full wp-image-42086" src="url of picture" alt="" width="280" height="23"></a></div>';
     }
    }}
```

You can put this in a child-theme version of your single-product.php page or use a hook in your functions.php